# need to process 5 billion records on mysql (amazon rds instance)

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I need to process almost 5 billion records which will be an output of two tables with 8.6 M and 1.3 M records, I am using amazon rds instance for MySQL database, I have developed a procedure which is processing these records, issue is speed of processing which is just 600-800 records/sec while I need 20k-30k records per second. I am unable to trace the issue either it is with amazon rds or with my procedure. I have 1 TB space, db.r3.8xlarge instance class 6000 IOPS.

Once the database was in EC2 instance it was running very fast but after selecting RDS its performance is degraded exceptionally low.

Comment: what instance type and storage does the RDS instance have?

Comment: It is amazon RDS instance and have storage Provisioned IOPS (SSD)

Comment: Elaborate on what "process" means.  There are _many_ ways to speed up "processing".